# How to add text to empty bullet points in Microsoft Word with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to add text to empty formatted bullet points in a word document, however I can't seem to find any successful way of doing so. I'm not very good at VBA, I just use it to automate reoccuring reports.

This is the format of VBA subs I've been using to find and replace text, I just can't find a way to adjust for adding to bullet points:

```
Private Sub FixedReplacements()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim SearchString As String
Dim EndString As String
Dim Id As String
Dim Link As String

Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range

    Rng.Find.ClearFormatting
    Rng.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Rng.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Rng.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

The goal I have set for empty bullet points is for them to display something along the lines of "No further information." << Just an example.

Comment: The first thing you need to determine is if the bullet point is a manually inserted character or whether it arises from a style format.  You then need to include the bullet point character in your find text.

Comment: @Freeflow these bullet points are the formatted bullet points found straight out of word. I'm not sure how to implement this into the script, are you able to give me some sort of idea on how to do so?

Comment: https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008259_Finding_Formatted_Bulleted_Paragraphs.html

Answer (score 0):

How this can be done depends very much on how the bullets were inserted. There is no way to specifically search the bullet, itself. A comment mentions

> bullet points are the formatted bullet points found straight out of
>   word.

In that case, the default setting would be to format the paragraphs with the `List Paragraph` style. If that's the case, here, then `Find` can search for paragraphs using that style. The `Find` code in the question would then look as follows. (Note also the changes to the `Format` and `Wrap` properties.)

```
With Rng.Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "No further information.^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Style = "List Paragraph"
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
```

If a different style has been used to apply bullets, then that style name can be searched. Keep in mind that style names are *case-sensitive*.

There is an option in File/Options/Advanced, Editing options section: Use Normal style for bulleted or numbered lists. If this has been activated then things become very difficult. Best you can do is to try to match the applied paragraph formatting (indents, etc.).